# xajax not executing when include is wraped in php if tags

Tags: php, xajax

I have and extremely weird problem. My page below.
on line 11 I basically include my xajax library and my php functions when user exists via the if($row_cnt == '1').

Now all the code works perfectly (When I remove the if statement), but it's like it's not including my xajax.inc.php file when it's in the IF statement.

When I close my IF statement after I declare $test and remove the else statement the code works 100% and it even pass the the $test value to my function correctly so I know my IF statement are true.

The exact code is running perfectly on 3 of my own servers but cant get it to run on my clients server. So I can only think it must be some kind of server setting that is doing this, but have no idea what setting it might be.

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file('config/config.ini'); 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($config['server'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname'],3306);
$_login_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['login_password']);
$sql = "SELECT 
a.`id`, a.`name`, a.`surname`, `username`, `password`, `user_level`   
FROM `comp_mfm_users` AS a 
WHERE (a.`username`='$_POST[login_username]' AND a.`password`='$_login_password') LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if($row_cnt == '1'){
$test = "IN";

include_once("xajax/xajax_core/xajax.inc.php");

$xajax = new xajax();

// Included Functions
require_once("functions/test.php");
// Request
$xajax->processRequest();
}
else{
$test = "OUT";
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php $xajax->printJavascript('xajax/'); ?>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        var php = "<?php echo "$test" ?>";
        clicks += 1;
        xajax_test(clicks,php);
    };
</script>
<div id="mainContent"><?php echo "$test" ?></div>
<input type="button" value="click Here" onclick="onClick();">
</body>
</html>
```

The function I'm calling:

```
<?php
$xajax->registerFunction("test");
function test($in,$in2){

$content = <<<EOF_
Teast Page : $in : $in2
EOF_;


$objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
$objResponse->assign("mainContent","innerHTML", $content);
return $objResponse;    
}
?>
```

Okay this is completely bowling me over. I tried a different approach and skip the IF statement to load the includes. Xajax still not executing. The php code is working, it's loading page when username and password is correct and it exit when it's not so again no error in the php code. But here comes the starnge part, when I remove:

```
if($stmt->num_rows !== 1){
echo "You are logged out";
exit();
}
```

All is good and everything is working except for there is no user verification. So I went one step further and moved the:

```
if($stmt->num_rows !== 1){
echo "You are logged out";
exit();
}
```

Below/After the Line:

```
// Request
$xajax->processRequest();
```

And all is working 100%. This doesn't make sense at all! I take the exact code and run it on my test server and it's working 100% with the code like it is below, but when I put it on the client server I have to move the IF statement down to the line mentioned above for it to work. The problem still is I can not use this code, it's not very good security the page can be halted before the exit(); command so I need the includes to be inside the IF statement.

So the real question is why is the client server behaving like this, it must be a php setting in the .ini file for but witch one is the million dollar answer.

Below Are the altered code with the IF statement still above the include where it's not working on client server but it's working on my test server.

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file('config/config.ini'); 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($config['server'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname'],3306);
$_login_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['login_password']);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
SELECT 
a.`id`, a.`name`, a.`surname`, `user_level`   
FROM `comp_mfm_users` AS a 
WHERE a.`username`=? AND a.`password`=? LIMIT 1
");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST[login_username], $_login_password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($myrow[id], $myrow[name], $myrow[surname], $myrow[user_level]);
$stmt->fetch();

if($stmt->num_rows !== 1){
echo "You are logged out";
exit();
}

include_once("xajax/xajax_core/xajax.inc.php");

$xajax = new xajax();

// Included Functions
require_once("functions/test.php");

// Request
$xajax->processRequest();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php $xajax->printJavascript('xajax/'); ?>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        var php = "in";
        clicks += 1;
        xajax_testpp(clicks,php);
    };
</script>
<?php
$dis = <<<EOF_
<div id="mainContent">$myrow[surname]</div>
<input type="button" value="click Here" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="onClick();">
EOF_;
echo"$dis";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Comment: Anyway have you verified that $row_cnt actually is 1 in the scenario you describe? Because otherwise it'll never enter the if block. You say it only happens on one server, so the obvious difference is that the values in the database are different and not returning the same results. Also strictly you should do `if ($row_cnt === 1)` (triple =, and no quotes round the 1) because $row_cnt is an int not a string. What you've written probably works due to PHP's penchant for loose type comparisons, but it's usually better to be precise.

Comment: Hi ADyson thanks for the reply. I'm using prepared statements in the "real" app, this is just a quick test page I made to try and get to the problem, but thanks for pointing it out. Like I mentioned the IF statement are TRUE it does have the value 1, I echo out the value of $test.

Comment: "this is just a quick test page I made to try and get to the problem". Then why did you say "he exact code is running perfectly on 3 of my own servers"? It's best to be clear about what you're showing. Anyway...if the if block is entered, then those mentioned PHP scripts must get included. The only thing that would stop it is if an error occurs of some sort. Have you got PHP error reporting switched on?

Comment: And is it possible that the scripts are included but that there's something failing on the client side, i.e. it's included but the JS part is not executing. Are there are any errors in your browser's console when running the relevant parts of the page?

Comment: The exact code is running on 3 of my server as well, I loaded it on so I can be sure it's working and there is nothing wrong with my code. So the problem is not the code, the code is working 100%. I only pasted the code so I can try and explain it. I'm sure it's a server setting but not sure where even to start looking.

Comment: hm. so let's be clear. On this client's server, the if block is entered, and then what? Presumably `include_once("xajax/xajax_core/xajax.inc.php");` is supposed to include some JS code in the final HTML page output? Is that correct? If so, are you saying that this JS isn't included in the page output? Or that it is included but doesn't execute properly? Big difference. It would help to clarify. Like I said, are there any errors in the browser console at any time when running the page from the client's server? That ought to give us a clue.

Comment: It does load the include, it's just not executing. I picked up something else, When I change the code a bit to: `$row_cnt = 1; if($row_cnt ==  '1'){...}` it's working. So something strange is going on at the `$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;` although when I echo it the value is 1, I also tried different variations like you suggested `if($row_cnt ===  1){...}` but still same result, it is going into the IF stament but it's not executing the function. There are no errors in php or in firefox developer tools.

Comment: Hi ADyson, please check above at the added content on original post I believe this will explain my problem more clearly. And also thank you for your responses it is much appreciated.